# SplitterDistance Property won't get smaller than 25 pixels

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

I have a split container within a split container, and when I set the SplitterDistance to anything less than 25 pixels, the SplitterDistance will not get smaller. I can make it smaller than 25 pixels during run-time with no problem. I can make it larger via the code or designer and during run-time no  problem. I want to set it to about 20 pixels, without the user having to re-size it. Does anyone know why it keeps reverting to 25 pixels, and if there is anyway to get it less than that?

I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
        // 
        // splitContainer3
        // 
        this.splitContainer3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.splitContainer3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.splitContainer3.Name = "splitContainer3";
        this.splitContainer3.Orientation = System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal;
        // 
        // splitContainer3.Panel1
        // 
        this.splitContainer3.Panel1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
        this.splitContainer3.Panel1MinSize = 5;
        // 
        // splitContainer3.Panel2
        // 
        this.splitContainer3.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.txtLineNums);
        this.splitContainer3.Panel2.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
        this.splitContainer3.Panel2MinSize = 5;
        this.splitContainer3.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
        this.splitContainer3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(47, 562);
        this.splitContainer3.SplitterDistance = 20;
        this.splitContainer3.SplitterWidth = 2;
        this.splitContainer3.TabIndex = 0;
        this.splitContainer3.TabStop = false;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a little more code to give the context of where you're setting it?  Have you tried setting a breakpoint on that line and ensuring that it's actually getting hit?

Comment: It's being set in the auto-generated Designer class. I did set a breakpoint, and it is breaking there.

Comment: Did you manually change the designer code? It may not behave the way you expect, if so. Either set it programmatically in your form or in the design mode.

Comment: Try the solution in a blank form, with nothing but the split container (use a border style to help you highlight the splitter location) and try the code I mentioned. This will help you rule out any other complicating factors, because reducing the MinSize appropriately does work.

Comment: Yes, I changed it manually and in design mode. Neither worked, for some reason, but setting it in the form class worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your split container panel MinSizes aren't set too high to go down to 20. The default panel MinSizes are 25. The splitter distance will go as low as it can without encroaching on it.

Panel sizes are set in the overall split-container properties. You can see this below:

[image]

Of course, you can always programmatically set them by drilling down into the split-container properties in your code:

```
splitContainer1.Panel1MinSize = 0;
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 20;
```

[Edit]

Further demonstration shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I added some more code. The MinSize is 5 for both panels, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.